# How to display y axis label in multiple lines in RGraph?

Tags: rgraph

Hi I am using RGraph in Angular 7 application. in the y axis i am showing names. instead of showing in one line i want to show in multiple lines. yaxisLabelsAngle: 25 is not working.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 3D style it looks like you have an older set of libraries so you may well need to update to the latest version (v6.00, which I just released this past weekend).

***You can add newlines in your labels by using \n like this example shows.***

Here's a codepen of an example 3D HBar chart:

https://codepen.io/rgraph/pen/MWJQRvX

For which the code is:

```
<script>
    new RGraph.HBar({
        id:'cvs',
        data: [[8,2],[6,4], [2, 5]],
        options: {
            grouping: 'stacked',
            marginInner: 10,
            variant: '3d',
            xaxis: false,
            yaxis: false,
            yaxisLabels: ['Richard\nDawkins', 'Neil de-Grasse\nTyson','Bill\nNye'],
            yaxisTitle: 'The Y axis title',
            xaxisTitle: 'The X axis title',
            colors: ['purple', 'gold'],
            key: ['A purple bar','A gold bar'],
            keyPosition: 'margin',
            keyPositionY: 15 // Might need to remove this
        }
    }).draw();
</script>
```